# Disable "10 repeater intervals were not enough"

Tags: org-mode

I sometimes get the message:

10 repeater intervals were not enough to shift date past today.  Continue? (y or n)

When I mark a repeating TODO as done.

I would not like to be asked this.

In other words, I would like the answer to this to always be "yes". Automatically.

I imagine there is a setting to set the number of repeater intervals to infinite or a large number or to disable this message.

I have not been able to find a setting to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no setting for this:

https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/7fa8173282f85c2ca03cc7f51f28f6adfb250610/lisp/org.el#L10425

You could try writing a patch to add a setting and submitting it to the org mailing list?

Comment: Thanks Croad for your response.
I am a grateful user of org mode but not a programmer so I would not be able to write a patch.